# How correct test anonymous controller if request action set in block subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I test resource controller. For this I created in test anonymous controller.

I have following rspec test:

```
describe '#destroy' do
    before { allow(controller).to receive(:custom_actions_path).and_return('/') }
    subject { delete :destroy, params: { id: post.id, locale: user.language }}

    it 'delete resource' do
      expect { Post }.to change(Post, :count).by(-1)
    end 

    it 'instant variables are exist' do
      assigns(:resource).should_not be_nil
    end

    it { expect(response).to redirect_to('/') }

    it { expect(response.code).to eq '302' }
  end
end
```

Tests always falls:

```
1) ResourceController::Crudify#destroy delete resource
     Failure/Error: expect { Post }.to change(Post, :count).by(-1)
       expected `Post.count` to have changed by -1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/unit/controllers/concerns/resource_controller/crudify_spec.rb:162:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:47:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) ResourceController::Crudify#destroy instant variables are exist
     Failure/Error: assigns(:resource).should_not be_nil

       expected: not nil
            got: nil
```

How correct test method destroy if request to action destroy i pass in block subject? Thank you

Comment: Please, add code for `destroy` action in the tested controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases you should call `subject` explicitly. Mind the first example: it should be passed to the block so `RSpec` can actually evaluate before and after states.

```
describe '#destroy' do
    before { allow(controller).to receive(:custom_actions_path).and_return('/') }
    subject { delete :destroy, params: { id: post.id, locale: user.language }}

    it 'deletes resource' do
      expect { subject }.to change(Post, :count).by(1)
    end 
end
```